# Сокращенный вывод числа

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 double x = 0;
 double y = 0;
 double c = 0;
 x = 547857483.5385738457;
 cout << x << endl;
 y = x * pow(10,-10);
 cout << y << endl;
 c = x + y;
 cout << c << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

1.97202e+010 как выводить число целиком, без e?

Comment: `cout.setf(ios_base::fixed, ios_base::floatfield);` перед выводом. Или просто `cout << fixed;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть много разных флагов, управляющих выводом. Возьмите `fixed`:

```
c = x + y;
cout << c << endl;
cout << fixed << c << endl;
```

Сравните два вывода...

```
5.47857e+08
547857483.593360
```

Comment: @EOF Гм. Я как-то привык, что все они там :) Спасибо, что указали.